# Python Invalid Syntax is my Whitespace

Tags: python

I am fairly new to python but I know a fair amount.  I made a simple program that adds items to a grocery list.  I had a problem where it closes as soon as the items are printed, so I was working on something to fix it.  Here is the entire program.

```
grocery_list = open('list.txt', 'a')
print 'This is your python grocery list project.'
newitems = raw_input('Add items (seperate with commas):')
grocery_list.write(newitems)
grocery_list = open('list.txt', 'r')
list = grocery_list.readlines()
print list
choice = raw_input('Do you want to close your grocery list? (y/n)')
if choice == 'y'
  exit()
elif
  raw_input("We're waiting, please enter y to close")
```

My problem now is, on line 9, the space after it is all invalid syntax!  What did I do wrong, and is there a better way to solve my problem of it closing as soon at it prints the items?

Answer (score 4):

You forgot a colon:

```
if choice == 'y'
```

should be

```
if choice == 'y':
```

Also, you need a condition (and a colon) after `elif`.

ETA: Also, the program will close on its own once it reaches the end, there is no need to call `exit()` (especially since all that happens if you type `n` is that it closes anyway). If you want to have the program wait for the user to type a key before the program exits, just do:

```
raw_input("Press enter to exit")
```

(No need to check what the input was).

Comment: or change `elif` to `else:` if there's only 1 condition to check

Answer (score 3):

you need `:` after your if and elif statement

the syntax should be like this:

```
    if condition:
        do..something..
    elif condition:
        do..something..
    else:
        do..something..
```

check out [here](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html) for more info